# How to get Text and Value of CheckBox with several way?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I already read the other article but still not solve it. I have check box that generate by :

```
$('#sel_div').append("<div style='margin-bottom:4px;margin-right:5px;float:left;width:80px;'><input type='checkbox' name=loc["+loc_id+"][] style='margin:2px;' value='"+myvalue+"' onClick='handler(this)'>"+description+"</div>");
```

**The question is , how to get value of checkbox (myvalue) and text of checkbox (description) ?**

What i have to do :

```
function handler(checkbox){
    var checkedValue = checkbox.value;
    alert(checkedValue);
    alert($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').next().val());
    alert($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').next().text());
}
```

The result :

checkedValue get correct value but the other alert shown blank.

Can anyone explain what wrong with the code ?

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @pekka-웃 : To get value of description and value of value attribute. Description is a variable name. (look to the code for more detail)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `closest()` to go up to the parent div then get the text :

```
$(checkbox).closest('div').text();
```

Since you're using jQuery I suggest to add the event listner in you JS code :

```
$('body').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function(){
    if( $(this).is(':checked') )
    {
         console.log($(this).val());
         console.log($(this).closest('div').text());
    }
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var myvalue = 'myvalue';
var loc_id = 'loc_id';
var description = 'description';

$('#sel_div').append("<div style='margin-bottom:4px;margin-right:5px;float:left;width:80px;'><input type='checkbox' name=loc["+loc_id+"][] style='margin:2px;' value='"+myvalue+"'>"+description+"</div>");


$('body').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function(){
  if( $(this).is(':checked') )
  {
    console.log($(this).val());
    console.log($(this).closest('div').text());
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='sel_div'></div>
```

**Multiple checkbox snippet :**

```js
var myvalue = 'myvalue';
var loc_id = 'loc_id';
var description = 'description';

$('#sel_div').append("<div style='margin-bottom:4px;margin-right:5px;float:left;width:80px;'><input type='checkbox' name=loc[1][] style='margin:2px;' value='value_1'>description_1</div>");

$('#sel_div').append("<div style='margin-bottom:4px;margin-right:5px;float:left;width:80px;'><input type='checkbox' name=loc[2][] style='margin:2px;' value='value_2'>description_2</div>");

$('#sel_div').append("<div style='margin-bottom:4px;margin-right:5px;float:left;width:80px;'><input type='checkbox' name=loc[3][] style='margin:2px;' value='value_3'>description_3</div>");

$('body').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function(){
  if( $(this).is(':checked') )
  {
    console.log($(this).val());
    console.log($(this).closest('div').text());
  }
})
```

```css
div{
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='sel_div'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be more easy if you will assign `label` for your checkbox like this:

```js
var text    = $('label[for=myCheckBox]').text();
var another = $('#myCheckBox').next('label').text();
console.log(text);
console.log(another);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" id="myCheckBox">
<label for="myCheckBox">Test Run</label>
```

**Note:** Please change the values accordingly.